# Are there countries aside from the US where I can go on storm chasing (tornado) tours?

Tags: tours, where-on-earth, adventure, extreme-tourism, natural-disasters

I've been fascinated with tornadoes for a long time, and I've always wanted to go on a storm chasing tour (e.g., http://www.stormchasing.com/).  However, I didn't get a chance to go on one before I embarked upon my project to live abroad for the next 5 years.

Are there any places outside the US that tend to get lots of tornadoes where I could go on a storm chasing adventure tour?

Comment: To clarify - does it have to have tornadoes? What about insane lightning storms, hurricanes or, I don't know, hail?

Comment: Good point.  Tornadoes are a must for me – to the extent they can guarantee that on any given tour, of course (:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's rare for tornadoes elsewhere, commercially at least.

From [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storm_chasing#Geographic_and_seasonal_activity):

> Some organized chasing efforts have also begun in the Top End of the
>   Northern Territory and in southeast Australia, with the
>   biggest successes in November and December. A handful of individuals
>   are also known to be chasing in other countries, including Israel,
>   Italy, Spain, France, Belgium, the Netherlands, Finland, Germany,
>   Switzerland, Bulgaria, Estonia, Argentina, and New Zealand; although
>   many people trek to the Great Plains of North America from these and
>   other countries around the world (especially from the United Kingdom).

Overall, Australia seems like your best bet.

It's mostly enthusiasts up north, but they're growing in numbers.  A nice report on it [is available on ABC](http://www.abc.net.au/7.30/content/2003/s1012266.htm), as well as [The Age](http://www.theage.com.au/articles/2004/07/03/1088488200242.html).

[Australia Severe Weather](http://australiasevereweather.com/storm_news/index.html) is probably your best bet for news on tornadoes and the like there, and [The Australian Severe Weather Association](http://www.severeweather.asn.au/) would be the one to follow or contact to find out about any commercial groups operating.

There are a few other random Storm Chasing websites in Aus, but they tend to be small individual groups, rather than commercial - however, you might find them keep to take you out for a trip, if you're lucky:

- [Aussie Storm Chasers](http://www.aussiestormchasers.com/)
- [Downunder Chasing](http://www.downunderchase.com/duc/)
- [Australia Storm Chasing](http://www.stormchasing.com.au/)
- [Melbourne Storm Chasers (on Australia Sky and Weather)](http://www.stormchasers.au.com/)

Finally, it's worth noting that most American Storm Chasing companies will keep an eye on the Canadian Prairies, especially during June - as there is the occasional opportunity for it up there, depending on the weather.

Answer (score 2):

I see this post is now 6 years old and you stated you're on a 5 year assignment, so you might be back in the USA now. If not, I recommend Jimmy Deguara at [Thunderbolt Tours](http://www.thunderbolttours.com/) in Australia. I'm from NSW and have chased with him on quite a few occasions. He's done a lot of chasing in the USA as well, but he's a local expert on Aussie weather. Last year I also went to the USA and chased with Brian Barnes' [storm chasing tours](https://www.stormtours.com), and it was absolutely an incredible experience! We actually lost count of the number of tornadoes we saw (somewhere around 30 in a single week!) whilst on tour. Both are highly recommended.